# Is there a way to see all my favorite questions?

Tags: support, bookmarks

Otherwise, what is the use of marking a question as a favorite?

Comment: to add more information to this question (not to second-guess the OP, but I believe this is relevant): especially across ALL SE sites, not just a specific SE site.

Comment: People who have added this post to their favorites have a great sense of humor :)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It's on the ["Bookmarks" tab of your user profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=favorites), which can be accessed via the link to your profile on every page, or directly by URL in the form of:

```
https://(stack-exchange-site).com/users/current?tab=favorites
```

Comment: In his case. http://superuser.com/users/8829?tab=favorites#sort-top

Comment: Something is wrong here! He can't have 4 pages with favourites, without knowing where to find them, can he?

Comment: ohh...thanks. i kept on marking questions as favorites. Today I needed to look at one of them and I couldn't find it! I've found it now.

Comment: @John apparently he can.

Comment: Perhaps he confused upvoting and marking as a favourite.

Comment: Don't forget that your favorites are "publicly visible". This sounds like a privacy issue.

Comment: @Myobis - I *think* I can see what you're driving at here, but is it a serious issue?

Comment: Serious enough that he would bother you in an answer that was posted 4 years ago (barring the edit as it didn't really change a whole lot about your answer).

Comment: @ChrisF - Just noticed that my concern was already discussed as [a distinct question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94826/is-seeing-other-peoples-favorites-a-privacy-issue/). From me, it was just a remark but some people have apparently made a personal mission of this!

Comment: I clicked on my profile, clicked the "profile" tab, and didn't find it. Thanks for including the direct link. I'd say "In the activities tab of your user profile, it's on the favorites tab".

Comment: Where can I find them in the Android app?

Comment: Ditto for mobile view. **Where is the favorites tab in mobile view?**