# How do I navigate to a list of all my favorite questions?

Tags: feature-request, bookmarks

How do I get a list of all questions that I've marked as a favorite?

I can manufacture my own URL as shown in [Is there a way to see all my favorite questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28824/), but is there a way to navigate to this list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Click your user name in the bar at the top of any given Trilogy (or StackExchange) site. Then click the Favorites tab.

If you're asking if there's a one-click navigation feature, then no. It's going to be two clicks (unless you happen to already be on your profile page).

You could use you're browser's bookmarks feature with the URL you create from [question 28824](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28824/linkety-linkety-all-right), as well. This would also give you quick-and-easy access.

Comment: I apologize for asking a question with such an obvious answer.  I didn't see the Favorites tab.

Comment: Don't apologize; it's a perfectly valid question. :)