# How can I view all questions I have favourited?

Tags: feature-request, bookmarks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to see all my favorite questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28824/is-there-a-way-to-see-all-my-favorite-questions)

I mark some questions as favourites but can't read all the answers at the same time. And now I can't find all the questions I have marked favourite. I need to wait for a new answer to be added to those questions, so that I get an alert that allows me to reach the question.

Is there a way already to find all my favourite questions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are in your Profile.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I had seen this screen before and forgot where to look at now, I was looking by clicking on inbox icon instead of clicking on my userID.