# How to view questions posted by others which I once marked as favourite?

Tags: support, bookmarks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to see all my favorite questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28824/is-there-a-way-to-see-all-my-favorite-questions)

I remember marking a few interesting questions posted by other people as favourite . But I don't find a way to see all the questions which i marked as favourite ?

Answer (score 2):

It's in your profile; you have tabs at the bottom right corner, (stats, activity, reputation, **favorites**, prefs, accounts)

Comment: Thank you I'm a newbie to stack-overflow thanks a lot!!!

Comment: I'm too :) thanks for getting me started with my reputation :D