# What are the rules on picking a site for room assignment on chat.se?

Tags: support, chat

As a mod on chat.se, I was asked to change [this room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/2439/room-for-josh-and-ben-brocka?tab=general#) from Stack Overflow to Cognitive Sciences, since that's the new parent site for this (still in pubbeta)

[image: http://i.imgur.com/CV4Yd.png]

Because I'm not affiliated with CogSci, I wasn't able to change the room to that site.

Where is this spec listed, or do we need to create a bit more proper [faq-proposed](/questions/tagged/faq-proposed) to list out what the rules are? (I don't mind this being closed as dupe, and if suggested as a faq-proposed I'll do a better image cleanup)

Additional bonus question: How do we show all sites in that list, instead of character restricted?

Comment: Looks like you'll have to have an account on the site you want to associate it to

Comment: But where is that currently documented, or do we need a faq-proposed?

Comment: Ah - I saw this problem a couple of days ago. It didn't click that the sites I was seeing were only those I had accounts for.

Comment: @jcolebrand This doesn't really seem like a frequently asked question, since it doesn't even apply to most of the user base and has never come up before. It seems broken that the list doesn't have all sites, unless there's some technical reason you need to have an account there to change a room's host

Comment: @MichaelMrozek fair point, but how about "we need to have all moderator tools documented on metaso, forever" ... don't we keep getting told that if something isn't documented in the tools, it needs to be on meta (and not just in TL lore or the minds of the now-mods)?

Comment: If it's just having the account, it seems like the dialog could just mention that itself.

Comment: @jcolebrand If it doesn't get added to the UI directly, you could toss it in [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119111/moderator-cheat-sheet/119117#119117)

Comment: Ok, so now all we need is a direct response to confirm expressly what the requirements are, yes @MichaelMrozek