# When should the code language associated with a tag changed from "none" to "default"?

Tags: support, tags, moderator-tools, syntax-highlighting

I noticed that for newly created tags, the code language (which is used when highlighting the code written in a post) is by default set to "none."

[image: screenshot]

I get there must be a reason for using that as default language, and I am wondering in which cases it is correct to set it to *default*, or any other value.

What should I do, before changing the code language set by default? Should I check there are questions/answers showing code snippets, and verify that is the common case for questions using that tag?

Comment: Just a note for people desperately trying to find that code language selector: It's a moderator-only functionality.

Comment: The question is not about Stack Overflow. As a matter of fact, I am a moderator on Drupal Answers, and I am more interested for that site. The answer is valid for every Stack Exchange site, though. [meta-tag:stackoverflow] should not be used for this question.

Comment: Yeah, the reasoning should be similar on any site, but the results may indeed differ.

Comment: This looks like it would be useful to add to the "tags" section of [The moderator cheat sheet](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119111/moderator-cheat-sheet) (if anyone uses that, that is).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A tag should *only* have a language other than "none" if the tag (by itself) is a strong indicator that the so-tagged question and its answers contain highlightable code (this is, for example, not true of the tag in your screenshot).

If that's the case, it should only have a highlighting language other than "default" (the one-size-tries-to-fit-all highlighter) if (obviously) there is a corresponding highlighter **and** it's fairly certain that a so-tagged question will *not* contain code in other languages. The [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) tag, for example, has its highlighter set to "default" despite "lang-js" existing, because questions in this tag have a fair chance of containing intermixed JS and HTML.