# Display Friendly Language Names in Tag Syntax Picker

Tags: feature-request, syntax-highlighting

When viewing information about a tag as a ♦, you have the option of enabling syntax highlighting for code blocks used within the question and answers.

[image: lang-ol]

I don't even know what some of these languages are. Is the 'lang-' prefix really necessary? Can this list be spruced up a bit in order to display the actual name of the language?

Comment: In many cases the bits after the `lang-` *are* the actual language names.

Comment: It would also be great if we non-♦ peons could specify the language for our post, using a nice pick-list like this, in cases where the overriding tag dictates a different language than the one we wish to use for our code samples.

Comment: @aar - If you don't post a FR to the tune of that - I will :P

Comment: @Lix [okay, done](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140329/please-provide-a-language-pick-list-for-syntax-highlighting).

Comment: @dmckee Out of 24 items, only 8 of those _are_ their actual name. I might be wrong on the few ones I don't know.

Comment: @VxJasonxV...I make it 13 counting abbreviation like css and html that are at least as common as the fully enunciated name.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about this one. Changing the default highlighting language for a tag should require quite some experience with both the corresponding language *and* the posts within that tag. Example: If it said "JavaScript" instead of "lang-js", it would just be too "obvious" to apply it to the [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) tag, which [would be wrong](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130952/115866).

So a bit of barrier is a good thing here. When in doubt, don't change it.