# Reading list to understand StackExchange type ecosystems

Tags: discussion, meta

I was thinking of putting on my reading list books, papers, and other resources that address different parts of the StackExchange ecosystem.

Another way to state this is that if I were to build a StackExchange like system (say for internal use at an organization) what should I read up on to get a rigorous understanding of the StackExchange class of applications.

Note: I am looking for aspects that are non-technical (as in not programming/hardware/infrastructure related):

1. Organizational Aspects
2. Community
3. UX
4. Editorial
5. ROI
6. Leveraging StackExchange like systems.

Further Note: I am NOT looking for technical details like the ones addressed by [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-build-the-stack-exchange-network).

Thanks.

Comment: [This is a good starting point](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-build-the-stack-exchange-network)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the note Sha, I was actually looking for the organizational, UX, knowledge Management, Community Management, etc. side of the house (and not the technical) side of the house.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a brief list of links to get you started.

**Community**

- [FAQ for Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites) (you'll need about 6-8 weeks to read everything here)
- [How do I participate in Meta Stack Overflow and not die trying?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44188/how-do-i-participate-in-meta-stack-overflow-and-not-die-trying)
- [Could we please be a bit nicer to new users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9953/could-we-please-be-a-bit-nicer-to-new-users)
- [Fastest Gun in the West Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem)
- [Why aren't people voting for questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9508/why-arent-people-voting-for-questions)
- [Recent Reputation History Changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123319/recent-reputation-history-changes)

**Moderation**

- [A Theory of Moderation](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)
- [Moderator Agreement](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/moderator-agreement)
- [Moderator Cheat Sheet](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119111/moderator-cheat-sheet)
- [Moderator Newsletter](http://modnewsletter.stackexchange.com/)

**Stack Exchange**

- [Blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/)
- [About](https://stackexchange.com/about)
- [Management](https://stackexchange.com/about/management)
- [Legal](https://stackexchange.com/legal)
- [Area 51 FAQ](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq)

Comment: Many thanks @Yannis, the resources that you've pointed out look very valuable. I am also interested in books, papers on the subject. Thanks.