# Real use of Chat?

Tags: discussion, chat

As reputation maintained by StackOverflow community, only on-topic real question are asked here and answered by people who have gained expertise in the field or by some who are still exploring(like me).

But I came across this feature of StackOverflow : **Chat**.

So, I thought people might be discussing technical stuff here too. But, anytime I visited, no technical discuss was going on. It was just daily stuff like:

- How are you? I am fine.
- Whats up with life?
- Got a new crush.

and many other like that.

Now, I am confused if this is a side feature provided by StackOverflow to get to know each other or it's just that it can't be monitored?

What is the real purpose of **Chat** on StackOverflow?

Comment: Should be technical mainly but at end we all are *human being* and not *robots* so bit casual is fine. Can you define what specific chat groups you talking about ?

Comment: Speak for yourself @Rikesh

Comment: @Rikesh but the chat actually contains bots ;)

Comment: WHAT?? humans?  here??? Jon Skeet will be most displeased

Comment: @Rikesh I am not trying to say that is wrong. I am just asking if that is what it is intended.

Comment: You may want to read [this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/do-trilogy-sites-need-a-third-place/), explaining the raison d'être of chat.

Comment: @Oded That was a nice read. And gives reason for creation of chat.

Comment: I am confused too. I can't get what the actual purpose of this feature is. Different users use it for different purposes. For me I only use [Tavern on the Meta](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta) when I have any doubt but not actual question and can't find any question related to it. Same applies to SO as well.

Comment: FYI, it is monitored. All chat content is logged and can be indexed by Google.

Comment: Luckily the Tavern is very no-nonsense, no chit-chat and focused on on-topic discussions @hims056. ;)

Comment: @hims056 well, the per-language chat rooms *should* be more or less professional, but I never visited so can't say for sure. The Tavern by its very definition was never related to being professional, more like a place for the meta'ers to relax.

Comment: Just to give an example, on Super User chat we like to invite people to ask shopping recommendation questions, or get troubleshooting help. There's a few off topic discussions but they are mostly about, well, computer stuff. You've probably just been to the wrong rooms.

Comment: PORN FOR ENGINEERS !!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### 1. To provide further explanations/clarifications for a post

For me, chat is there to facilitate another channel of communication. We wouldn't want to limit users to discussions only in the comments.

Looking directly at Stack Overflow, the topics there usually require a little more in depth explanations and answers. Users at different levels of competence will all see the same answer and some might need further explanations. This point could also be valid for other Stack Exchange sites.

Chat is a place to have lengthy discussions that tend to deviate from the original topic. It facilitates a more active discussion than a comment thread (even with live updates) could ever provide.

The system actively encourages this once a post has received a certain number of comments. A message is displayed above the comment box saying:

> Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?

---

#### 2. To facilitate internal communications

The chat servers are also used internally to facilitate communication between the Stack Exchange team/Community managers and our team of mods. This is a private room that only diamond studded users have access to. It's called [The Teachers Lounge](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/4/teachers-lounge).

---

#### 3. To facilitate private communication with moderators

[Private chat rooms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/119114/172936) can also be used to allow a moderator to reach out to a specific user in order to resolve some issue with their account or some content issue. Mods even have a "super ping" feature that allows them to ping any user in the network even if the user is not currently in chat.

Answer (score 14):

The real answer is really, really simple.

### There is no real use for chat

That's it. Once you grasp this fact, you understand the meaning of chat.

Comment: Kind of a Zen thing, huh?

Comment: haha..this seems to be the perfect answer. :)

Comment: Voting to *close* this answer: *unclear what you're answering*.

Comment: @hims056 42 for you.