# Add link to the Moderators FAQ to the Moderator Nominations page

Tags: feature-request, election, nominations, election-page

Currently IIRC the nomination page has links to "[a theory of moderation"](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/) and "[moderator agreement](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/moderator-agreement)", but it's quite hard to find out what exactly a moderator can do and is expected to do.

I think it would be useful to provide a link to the [moderator FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118972/stack-exchange-moderator-faq) on the nomination page. It might also be handy to link to the "[Moderator Cheat Sheet](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119111/moderator-cheat-sheet)".

The SE search facility is not designed to find pages like that, and external search engines really struggle. A Google search for "[stack exchange moderator faq](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=stack%20exchange%20moderator%20faq)" does not return the actual FAQ on the first page of results, for example. There's an argument that we expect moderators to be somewhat competent at finding things on the site, and interested in what's involved with being a moderator. But I think it's unreasonable to expect people to plug away with different search terms and browsing just to find the basic documents.