# What do all these things that a moderator can do mean?

Tags: support, moderator-tools

Recently, I saw a bunch of images showing what a mod can do. I'm just wondering, what do the options mean?

For example, what's the difference between "destroy" and "delete" a user?

And what's annotate a user?

And how do you convert an answer to an edit?

Comment: Your name makes me sad.

Comment: "delete" just removes the user, "destroy" deploys cruise missiles to the user location as well.

Comment: @Amelia why? Unicorns __are__ yummy!

Comment: You are evil. Unicorns are sacred.

Comment: Have you seen the [Moderator Cheat Sheet](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119111/moderator-cheat-sheet) ?

Comment: You really should focus on asking one question at a time. This is way too broad.

Comment: I've duped you to another post covering the first question you asked.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> what's the difference between "destroy" and "delete" a user?

- destroy removes the user account and **all** posts by that user.
- delete removes the user account and any negatively voted posts they own.

The former is used for spammers and other types not welcome on the sites, the latter for other users who may have contributed valuable (i.e. positively scoring) content.

> what's annotate a user?

This is basically adding a note to the user's account for the next moderator who comes along.

> how do you convert an answer to an edit?

This is for questioners who may be unsure of how Stack Exchange works and have added extra information as an answer rather than editing the question. So on that answer you bring up the mod menu, select that option and press "Submit" and as if by magic the answer is deleted and appended to the question as an edit.