# What reputation-based privileges are not awarded as part of moderator rights?

Tags: support, reputation, privileges, moderators

I was working on updating the FAQ [What are the reputation requirements for privileges on sites, and how do they differ per site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58587/reputation-requirements-compared), which says that despite most privileges of 25k+ users being conferred as part of ♦ moderator rights, there are a few (4.5 technically) that are not awarded as part of it, and the check only checks for the required reputation. The [FAQ on moderators](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75189/who-are-the-diamond-moderators-and-what-is-their-role) also says the same thing (after I edited it). These include:

- Voting in moderator elections
- Answering protected questions
- Not being prompted to comment when downvoting (counted as half, since it doesn't actually restrict one from doing anything)
- Having a network-wide flair

These may not be relevant when it comes to most active moderators (which are elected), but does come in handy when it comes to new pro-tem moderators on beta sites, automatically-appointed moderators on beta site pro-tem elections where they had only 300 rep (the minimum required to nominate), and (most importantly) SE staff, who have network-wide moderator rights but usually have only 1 or 101 rep on sites. The case about network-wide flairs is relevant because the list of CMs here contains flairs, and there was one case where a CM didn't have the required rep despite having mod rights so they showed up as an unsightly sad face emoji there.

Comment: Given Robert Cartaino's edit to the list of Community Managers, it seems like those with moderator rights do not have the ability to have a flair (which requires at least 200 rep on a single site)

Comment: Indeed, this is the 'Flair Fail' image: https://stackexchange.com/users/flair/175974.png - given when someone doesn't have 200+ on a visible site.

Answer (score 13):

## Reputation Leagues

Although this is not listed in the Help Center as a privilege, only those with 201 rep or more show up in the leagues. Just look at the last page of the results on any site, such as [here](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/427/alltime/windowsphone/2012-04-24?sort=reputationchange&page=5) or search for the name of a diamond employee. Also, even when a diamond moderator/employee is on the list, no diamond is shown beside their name.

## Bounties?

I can't test this, but I assume that it's not possible to give away more rep than you have, even if you also have moderator privileges. I am not sure if this means that it is unlocked like normal ([75 rep](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties)) or at 51 (because the minimum bounty amount is 50).

Comment: Since the FAQ lists that together with seeing vote counts, can mods without 1,000 rep see vote counts?

Comment: @sonic Yes, they can

Comment: @Catija Can moderators give out 50-rep bounties while having only 51-74 rep?