# What happens to a user who has received a ton of downvotes?

Tags: discussion, reputation, down-votes, stack-exchange-team, downvoted-questions

I was always curious to what happens to users that have a ton of downvotes on their question/topics. Maybe I'm just finding this unfair for this guy. After all, he is just doing his job to post an update, and his rep is going down for it.

[We're testing advertisements across the network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/329763/282094)

Comment: I know this needs a bit of mind juggling but the votes are on the content. By definition those are never unfair. And that specific user signed up/got hired for also posting unpopular requests. We still love him.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

His reputation isn't going down by that much; the question has (while I'm writing this) 160 upvotes (= +800 reputation) and 514 downvotes (= -1028 reputation). That's only 200 points, which is easily gained when he posts an announcement which *is* well received.

Oh, and since he has a ♦, he doesn't lose any privileges. So nothing to worry about... After all, reputation is just some imaginary Internet points, nothing important. I heard "being the scapegoat from time to time" is part of the CM job description.

Comment: If he gets back to 1 he needs to report to Tim Post ...

Comment: Are you saying that when you become a moderator you automatically receive *all* possible privileges? It was my understanding that while moderators received many (or most) privileges, some are based *only* on reputation, regardless of moderator status. And I would assume that those could still be lost.

Comment: @JasonBassford: That may be, but actual SE staff people are... people on SE staff. If they can't be trusted with all of the tools of the site, they really shouldn't be on staff. So there is a difference between elected moderators and SE staff members.

Comment: @JasonBassford correct, but they are [so few and unimportant](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/326808/295232) that I felt a generalization ("any privileges") was appropriate.