# What is the reference date for reputation levels regarding moderator elections?

Tags: support, reputation, election

The entry on the [community wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135360/theres-an-election-going-on-whats-happening-and-how-does-it-work) answered all but one of my questions regarding moderator elections.

I understand that 300 (3000 on SO, 1000 on Mathematics.SE) reputation is needed to nominate yourself, and 150 reputation to be eligible to vote.

Is there, and if so, what is the reference date of these reputation levels? For instance, should the reputation be reached *before* the nomination phase? Can I still vote if I pass 150 reputation during the last day of the election?

Wouldn't it be appropriate to add the answer to this question to the wiki entry?

Comment: Meta doesn't have elections, uniquely. At the current point of time, this is the only site with appointed not elected moderators.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can vote/nominate if your *current* reputation is 150/300/.... Likewise for any badges needed to nominate. For votes, I conducted an experiment (but I can't find a reference to it) where my votes remained visible after my reputation dropped to below 150 (of course, I can't prove they made it to the ballot count, but I would assume so). I have also [voted in elections](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/help/badges/83/constituent?userid=16159) where I reached the [150 reputation level](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lm8aQ.png)<sup>*</sup> during the [nomination phase](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/election/2).

This is true for *all* privileges on Stack Exchange, that's perhaps why it's not in the wiki. If I upvote a post and then my reputation drops to below 15, the upvote is not cancelled.

I do not know how/when the "750,753 voters were eligible" statistics are determined.

<sup>*</sup><sub>: if you pay close attention to that screenshot, you can deduce that I should have had 149 reputation when I voted; apparently a post with one of my suggested edits has been deleted meanwhile.</sub>

Comment: Just to make this explicit: your experiment proves that *dropping* below the required level after the start of an election does not invalidate your vote. It does not confirm that *reaching* the reputation level after the election period has started also makes you eligible to vote. [Check for example this election](https://stackoverflow.com/election/12), where they mention "750,753 voters were eligible". Can I deduce that 750,753 user had 150 reputation *at any point* during these elections?

Comment: Just a remark regarding your sentence: "This is true for *all* privileges". Exceptional here is that voting nor nomination are listed in the [privileges overview](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges).

Comment: That may have something to do with them being [solely reputation based](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/326808/295232), in other words staff/moderators don't qualify for them automatically. They *are* mentioned in the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/58587/295232).