# How does it look for the moderators that I was already contacted in a moderator message?

Tags: support, moderator-tools, moderator-messages

For those not familiar with moderator messages, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/119106/147015:

> Sending a mod message (whether suspension is included or not) puts a permanent mark / annotation on the user's account as well as notifies the other moderators on the site and several Stack Exchange employees. Do not use it to respond to the user's flags or for other non-serious issues.

As I understood, having such a mark, i.e. if I was once contacted by a moderator, will be visible for the moderators forever.

Where is it visible? On my user page, in my flair, in some moderator-only user information page (if there is)? What exactly does a moderator see?

Although there are no disadvantages in the SE rules linked directly to this mark, the formulation clearly shows that it is not a positive thing. It corresponds well that a moderator message happens always regarding some serious circumstance.

I am only curious; what does a moderator see as they see my mark/annotation on my user page, to get a better understand on their actions and decisions?

P.S. I have this mark on most of my higher-rep accounts, thus moderators of these sites can make a screenshot in two clicks.

Comment: I think a screenshot would be particularly helpful, if it doesn't violate some internal mod standard.

Comment: "some mod-only user info page" <- this.

Comment: @yannis Thanks. Thus, it is not my profile (as the mods see it, including my deleted posts and probably many others), rather a specific view?

Comment: [Like this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/heVBw.png), to be completely accurate.

Comment: @Mithrandir Thanks again! The number means how many times was I contacted?

Comment: Essentially, yes. So the number changes.

Comment: 10 downs, no explanation... my dear 11th downvoter, don't you think, it says more from you, as from the post?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Where is it visible? On my user page, in my flair, in some mod-only user info page (if there is)? What exactly does a mod see?

If you are contacted, all mods (on that site) can see the number of times you've  been contacted  in an [orange square](https://i.stack.imgur.com/heVBw.png) on a mod dashboard linked from your profile. Beside this we can see how many of your posts have been flagged also. The intention (I suspect) is to be able to get an overview of the user's behaviour in one place.

Comment: All mods **for the site in question**. Community Managers can also see this information.

Comment: We can also see the content of the message, any response to it, and  when it happened, so we aren't acting from just the number.